# How to minimize SWT UI from taskbar if SWT.NO_TRIM is used

Tags: java, swt, taskbar, minimize

I have a SWT UI where I use SWT.NO_TRIM , this removes the minimize functionality from the taskbar when clicked. Is there a way to emulate the minimize function from the taskbar ?

Answer (score 1):

You can call

```
shell.setMinimized(true);
```

to minimize a Shell. Use `setMinimized(false)` to restore.

Comment: Thanks for your reply greg. Can I use these statements directly in a shell listener or do I have to get hold of the taskbar item and then use them on its listener ?

Comment: I think you would have to add a menu item to the taskbar and do the minimize in the menu listener.

Comment: Oh ok. Can we not minimize/restore just by clicking instead of adding a seperate menu entry? It seems more elegant that way...This is what I'm trying to achieve

Comment: You could try a mouse listener or something. I use a Mac which were there things work differently.